# What does it mean to say creating class at runtime ? and also what does runtime mean in python?

Tags: python, class, object, dynamic, runtime

I was going through Documentation, the python tutorial about classes, and I found this line very confusing. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

> As is true for modules, classes partake of the dynamic nature of Python: they are created at runtime, and can be modified further after creation.

What does it mean by 'class partake of the dynamic nature of Python' : they are created at runtime? and why is it true for modules?
what I have learned till now about classes is they are created as,

```
class Democlass():
    pass
```

Am I creating it at runtime? after googling I found [Here](https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/python-class-dynamically.html) that classes can be created at runtime by the below code, but I could not understand why it is represented as a runtime creation and the above code not, What is the difference between the two?

```
cls = type('A', (object,), {'__doc__': 'class created by type'})

print(cls)
print(cls.__doc__)
```

what is link between the 'dynamic nature of python' and its 'runtime'?
I will be really grateful if someone helps.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What it means is that `class` is an *executable statement* in Python, unlike compiled languages where the class resides in the compiled code  before execution starts.

Comment: @BoarGules are those two pieces of code for creating class same? i mean, are they doing the same thing?

Comment: They do, but the second way lets you determine the class name at runtime, in response to user input, say. It's the sort of thing that framework authors do. Ordinary mortals like us use the `class` statement.

Comment: thank you . Can you explain, what do you mean by runtime?

Comment: Runtime is when you type `python.exe mycode.py`. Before that, the classes don't exist.

Comment: `runtime` means `time when code runs` (time when code is executed by CPU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it is creating the class when running the program and can be changed while   running the program